# Using uncommon delimiter to parse .txt file using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

I have a .txt file that is:

16A:0617XXXXX
17B:560-L
18C:AID0005345

I'm trying to parse it from one cell into two cells using an uncommon delimiter, the colon ':'.

I tried to follow a simple parse guide and my code is:

```
with open('/u/ISIN.txt', 'r') as ISIN_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(ISIN_file)

    with open('/u/ISIN_new.txt', 'w') as ISIN_file_new:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(ISIN_file_new, delimiter=':')

        for line in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

The problem is, when the new file is the same as the old file. I'm wondering if there is a problem using a non-standard delimiter?

Comment: You are reading a regular file, without any defined delimiters so I bet it's using the comma. If you print an intermediate result, you'll see that nothing is split and so nothing needs joining again. You get exactly the same file.

Comment: @usr2564301 I tried to changed the first block to with open('/u/ISIN.txt', 'r') as ISIN_file:
 csv_reader = csv.reader(ISIN_file, delimiter=':') but that didn't seem to work. Is there a different way to define my delimiters?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
import csv

with open('jay.txt') as jay:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(jay, delimiter=':')
    with open('jay.csv', 'w', newline='') as jay_out:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(jay_out)
        for line in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

produces this result:

```
16A,0617XXXXX
17B,560-L
18C,AID0005345
```